# An external struct declaration, but the struct definition is just above

Tags: c, struct, stdio

I double-checked all the similar questions here, I really hope not to duplicate.
I am intrigued by the the following extract from stdio.h:

```
typedef struct _iobuf {
    /* Members here omitted ... */
} FILE;
extern FILE _iob[20];
```

We define a new type named FILE by using the struct syntax. Just after that, we declare an *extern* variable _iob of type FILE. Therefore, this variable must come from another place.
But, since the definition of FILE is in this file, how can it be possible? I see two possibilities only.
The first is to have something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
FILE _iob[20] = /* definition */
```

The second is to have another source file where the struct is copy-pasted and the variable declared, I guess a very bad practice that we can omit.

Since I am a self-learner, I would be very happy to receive a confirm of my understanding.Thanks!

Comment: The `typedef` defines the layout of the data type `FILE`. The `extern` says that the code has one of those at its disposal, but its location is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I follow what you mean. But somehow it sounded "strange" to say something like: "we define a type, only here, and then a variable of this type that can comes from another source". I mean, how can that source know the type definition? I am glad I asked, since it helped a lot in clarifying some C syntax. Have a nice day.

Comment: The `typedef` can be repeated elsewhere without issues. Yes, it's true that it's normal to have the definition in one header file only and include that everywhere, but it's not a requirement.

Comment: But wouldn't be the repetition of 'typedef' a very bad practice? Concerning the remaining comment, thanks, crystal clear.

Comment: Yes, it's never a good idea to have multiple definitions of the same thing.

Comment: _Great_, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- somewhere in the library source code files, there is text as you describe, an inclusion of `<stdio.h>` followed by a definition of `FILE _iob[20]`, or
- somewhere in the library source code files, there is a definition of `_iob` written in a programming language other than standard C.

The latter may be assembly language, non-standard C with extensions, or something else. An implementation of C is not required to use only C source code to define itself.

In general, it is good practice for the source file that defines an object to also include its own header. A primary purpose of a header file is to tell other source files about things defined in the associated source file. But including the header file in the source file serves another purpose: The compiler will see both the declarations in the header and the definitions in the source file and will issue error messages if they are incompatible. So this provides a check that catches typos or other errors when building the library.

Comment: Fantastic explanation: thank you so much!
Ps: it seems that I cannot upvote you answer since I have not enough reputation. I promise I'll do in the future, when possible.